# SASS - combination of two classes using variable

Tags: sass

I expected to get combination classes with use of variable which refers to component class name but it doesn't output anything

```
.component-name {
  $this: &; // $this = '.component-name'

  &--small { ... }

  &--secondary {
    &.#{$this}--small { // THIS doesn't work
      // Should output .component-name--secondary.component-name--small
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Now I see. My '$this" variable holds '.component-name' with a dot and when I tried to combine it with another class it was trying to output `.component-name--secondary..component-name--small`. Instead of `&.#{$this}--small` I should use `&#{$this}--small` (without dot between & and #{$this})

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do, but on first look, one way I got this to work was by setting the class name variable first.

```
$compname: component-name;

.#{$compname} {

  &--small {
    //font-size: 1px;
  }

  &--secondary {
    //font-size: 2px;

    &.#{$compname} {
      &--small {
        font-size: 3px;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Outputs `.component-name--secondary.component-name--small { font-size: 3px; }`

Comment: It's better in my opinion to use `$this: &` insted of holding class name in outside variable. Then `$this` holds current component's class name with a dot at the beginning

Comment: Yeah, I didn't realize that it took the selector element with it. Makes sense though. That's quite useful to know.